# Perl and DBD::mysql Can't load mysql.so... Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected

Tags: mysql, perl, dbd

Running this code on a shared host with a locally installed perl and modules which were installed via perlbrew. It worked fine for several weeks. One day, it started dying with this output:

```
/home/xxxx/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/bin/perl tweet.pl
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/home/xxxx/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/lib/site_perl/5.16.2/x86_64-linux/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /home/xxxx/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/lib/5.16.2/x86_64-linux/DynaLoader.pm line 190. 
at (eval 27) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 27) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
at subroutines.pm line 3.
```

The code hasn't changed. The way I run the script hasn't changed, either. Since I am running this one a shared host, I have no idea what might have been updated or changed on the server, but perl is installed to my home directory, as are all the modules I am using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with libmysqlclient. What distribution are you running?

If you are running Debian(based), try "sudo apt-get purge libmysqlclient libmysqlclient-dev" and then "sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient libmysqlclient-dev".

Comment: It's shared hosting. It looks like they did upgrade libmysqlclient.so.15 to libmysqlclient.so.16, and removed libmysqlclient.so.15. How do I tell perl to look for libmysqlclient.so.16 instead?

Comment: Try reinstalling DBD::mysql